# How to change idp claim value in JWT / Identity Server 4 implicit flow?

Tags: identityserver4

I noticed the "idp: local" in the jwt.  What is the best way to change the idp claim value from "local" to "FooIDP"?

Working off of Quickstart3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication quickstart sample for Identity Server 4.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way, but it looks like you need to change the call to SignInAsync in the AccountController::Login

Old:
`await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, props);`

New:
`await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, idpName, props);`